# JQuery selector: select td if sibling has .class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Hello I would like to select the first td of a row if one  of that row has .foo class

```
<tr>
    <td>Holland</td>
    <td>Usa</td>
    <td>Japan</td>
    <td class="foo">France</td>
    <td>Spain</td>
</tr>
```

So in this code I would like to get Holland.

Note: later I will need to append a string "Welcome to" to the  node. I.E: "Welcome to holland".
Note2: I have multiple  rows and multiple table element in my html code so it is not so easy to find the good selector I need

Comment: `$('td.foo').siblings().first()`

Comment: Thank you. Your code is also working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`:has()`](http://$(%22tr:has(td.foo)%20td:first%22))** and **[`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)** for that

```js
$("tr:has(td.foo) td:first-child").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Holland</td>
    <td>Usa</td>
    <td>Japan</td>
    <td class="foo">France</td>
    <td>Spain</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Holland</td>
    <td>Usa</td>
    <td>Japan</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>Spain</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Holland</td>
    <td>Usa</td>
    <td>Japan</td>
    <td class="foo">France</td>
    <td>Spain</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir It works perfectly. I do not understand why Somebody voted down on my question but thank you. I need to wait 5 minute to be able to accept your answer

Comment: @zm455 : glad to help you :) .... i dont knw why someone downvoted your question .....